# Finding Exact Value $7\csc(x)\cot(x)-9\cot(x)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

The values for $x$ on $[0,2\pi)$ solving $7\csc(x)\cot(x)-9\cot(x)=0$ are?

I think that $\dfrac{\pi}2$ is one but I can't find the others. what are the others?

Comment: You think, or did you verify. And while not a proof, did you make a graph to see what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

$7\csc x\cot x-9\cot x=0\implies7\cos x-9\cos x\sin x=0\implies (\cos x)(7-9\sin x)=0$,

so $\cos x=0\implies x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$

and $\sin x=\frac{7}{9}\implies x=\sin^{-1}\frac{7}{9}$ or $x=\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac{7}{9}$.